# File and print sharing disabled after each reboot

Tags: windows-xp, reboot

I have an XP Pro SP3 fully patched, T60 notebook with recent install of the OS, all drivers present and updated. It is set up with local home network.

In my Local area connection properties, the "File and print sharing for Microsoft Networks" tick box is unchecked on every reboot, I must check it every time after a reboot.

I have updated my network driver to the latest available with no change, looks like all the other needed protocols are installed and remain checked.

Windows firewall is turned off, I even disabled it in Services, no change.

Maybe something in group policy?

Any suggestions are welcomed, I have never seen this behavior before.

Comment: So is the machine part of a domain?

Comment: No. local home network

Comment: Glad you figured it out. After I asked that question, I rebooted my server, and it did not come back up...always scary. The PSU went bad...it was totally black. Thankfully, I stock every part just in case. On another note, I also have a T60 2.16 dual core. I will tell you that changing to Windows 7 64-bit extended the life of it by at least three years. I probably would have replaced it by now, but it runs so much better on 64-bit.

Comment: Which processor in your T60? Mine has the T2400 core duo, I don't think it supports 64bit, :-<

Comment: I have a T7400, but you are right, yours is only 32-bit. I didn't think they even made any that late that could not do 64-bit. I am very surprised. http://ark.intel.com/products/27235

Comment: I can pick up a T5500 fairly cheap, T7400's are high as a cats back...http://www.superbiiz.com/detail.php?name=T5500&c=FR&pid=0d9074ce138612c492bc3ffe6cd8d27fef6c4dbfb50639d2dd54e8cecca19dfa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

Thinkpads have a Think Vantage Access Connections software, by default file and print sharing is disabled on all connections, badah boom its fixed.

> 1. Double click on the ThinkVantage Access Connections applet in the
>      notification area.
> 2. Click on the MANAGE button on the toolbar
> 3. Select the SSID (or other network connection) where you want File Sharing to work, and click EDIT
> 4. Click on the ADDITIONAL SETTINGS tab
> 5. Next to "Network Security", click the SETTINGS button
> 6. The first option in Security Settings is "Disable file and printer
>      sharing". UNCHECK this box. Click OK for 3 levels of dialog boxes, then
>      close Access Connections

[Found the answer in post #7 here](http://forums.techarena.in/windows-vista-network/770671.htm)

Comment: Yay OEM software!

Comment: Yeah, I should have suspected that right off.